# getElementById Where Element is dynamically created and appended to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

I'm executing 2 scripts. The first script (jquery) creates an input and appends it to a form. The second script grabs the value of the dynamically created input. But right now I'm getting null value. To get every question out of the way, yes the first script has been tested multiple times and the input is indeed created and the value appended properly. How do I get the value from the dynamically created Element in the second script?

first script

```
<script src="js/firstscript.js"></script>
  $(document).ready(function(e){
    $('.button').click(function(e){

      e.preventDefault();
      var userCurrency = 'usd';

      $('<input>').attr({
        type: 'hidden',
        id: 'userCurrency',
        name: 'userCurrency',
        value: userCurrency
      }).appendTo('#payment-form');

  })
})
```

second script

```
<script>
  //get currency
  var amountCurrency = document.getElementById('userCurrency');
  console.log(amountCurrency);
</script>
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Well your second script executes immediately, you need that code to execute _after_ you've added the element. Just because the script tag itself comes after the first one does not mean it executes after some event handler.

Comment: @PatrickEvans: Okay yes. Mind showing off? :-)

Comment: @Sadie — When do you want to get the value? Write your code in a function that runs *at that time*.

Comment: @Quentin : The first script triggers/opens a modal with a form and append the value inside that form. I'm wanting to retrieve the value when the modal is opened.

Comment: @Sadie But why? That doesn't make sense since the user hasn't had a change to change it yet. When the modal is opened, the value is `usd`. Does the modal have an "Apply" button or something?

Comment: @ChrisG : This is a minimal code as we are suggested to post on here. The currency will not always be usd. It changes based on the user country. Now I need to retrieve the value and post it to the Paypal javascript so that I can trigger the right clientid or sandboxid. That's it. It's not really complicated.

Comment: @Sadie **HOW AND WHEN** does it change? Can the user change it? Or is it somehow determined by your website? If the user can pick the currency, you're supposed to grab it *after* they changed it, obviously, right? Why is it so difficult to see that the question makes no sense right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem and I basically just mix jquery and javascript together. Yeah I know bad practice whatnot but for now it works flawlessly and that's what matters for the team.

So in short that's the end result. Nothing magic but it did it for me :

```
<script src="js/firstscript.js"></script>
  $(document).ready(function(e){
    $('.button').click(function(e){

      e.preventDefault();
      var userCurrency = 'usd';

      $('<input>').attr({
        type: 'hidden',
        id: 'userCurrency',
        name: 'userCurrency',
        value: userCurrency
      }).appendTo('#payment-form');

  })
})

//vanilla javascript code below
var amountCurrency = userCurrency;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want these scripts be separated between each other, you can use this event handler:

```
document.getElementById('payment-form').addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (ev) {
  if (ev.target.id === 'userCurrency') {
    console.log(ev.target.id);
  }
}, false);
```

It would fire then your element append to form.

In other case if you can join scripts you should place your second script after appending of your element or call global function